# Profiling a Python Web Application

Tags: python, profiling, pyramid

I wrote a web app with Pyramid in python, but I'm struggling to find a suitable profiler. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using pyramid 1.2a1 or better you might try the [pyramid_debugtoolbar](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_debugtoolbar). [linesman](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/linesman) also seems like a pretty good choice.

Comment: Does the debugtoolbar allow you to see the individual times of all the function calls?

Comment: @Wiz: the screenshots on linesman's home page shows that it does cumulative times for functions.

Comment: Yea I saw, its interesting. Ill look into it! Thanks.

Comment: linesman worked for me. I don't saw in the documentation, but there is a way to get the cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: I wrote a simple blog post regarding this topic https://mitjafelicijan.com/profiling-python-web-applications-with-visual-tools